# Coded UI execution is extremely slow than usual?

Tags: automated-tests, mstest, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have coded UI project with five UIMaps.One of the UIMap is very large and it covers several features of the testing application.suddenly the coded UI playback become so slow. I separate some features from the large UIMap into separate UIMaps. But still some of the test methods running very slower than usual.Is there any solutions to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out after a search in the net, the class name of the main window is changed because of the latest releases. I have check the latest main window name and add it in the UIMap constructor as instructed in the following link [Mathew Aniyan's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mathew_aniyan/archive/2011/03/01/smart-match-amp-slow-coded-ui-tests.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below settings in your TestInitialize part and check whether this solves your purpose.As now we don’t need to add the annoying Sleep statements whenever a UI Control is busy and not ready to receive input. 
By default, the engine checks the UI Thread (foreground thread) to determine if a control is ready.
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;

By implementing this you can reduce the execution time.

Comment: `Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyLevel = WaitForReadyLevel.Disabled;` is not solved the slowness issue of playback. Do u think recreating UIMap will solved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I can not comment yet so here is an answer.

I had the same problem. see [Coded ui Test fails at random times on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24914126/coded-ui-test-fails-at-random-times-on-server/25120952#25120952)

waitforcontrolready was a solution next to PropertyExpressionOperator.Contains to search for a variable title. But also check the controlID of your control in your UIMap. It can change depending which windows are open on screen.
I remove them all unless I am 100% sure it stays the same.

Comment: Yes, removing controlID may help to run playback faster in some situations. But I used to addSearchConfiguration.AlwaysSearch property for some dynamic controls. when I add this property for upper hierarchy controls like window, it automatically slow down the playback because it needs to search from the beginning every time it uses the child control of the window.